# How to change the text alignment throughout the app at once?

Tags: objective-c, localization, text-alignment

Is there a way to change the alignment of all the textual elements (i.e textfileds, button titles, labels, navigation bar titles etc) throughout the app at once programatically? Actually I am developing a multi language app that has a language in which the text alignment is RTL. I dont want to set the alignment of every text element manually.There are some restrictions, so NSTectAlignmentNatural could not solve my problem. Actually the translations for languages arecoming through an API and that too in unicode format. So, how would the system detect what language is going to be displayed so that it could decide the alignment.

Comment: Ar you going to localize the app? Can't you use `NSTextAlignmentNatural`?

Comment: @Willeke there are some restrictions, so NSTectAlignmentNatural could not solve my problem. Actually the translations for languages arecoming through an API and that too in unicode format. So, how would the system detect what language is going to be displayed so that it could decide the alignment.

Comment: Add this information to the question.

Comment: @Willeke added..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) to set properties of ui elements throughout your entire app. This will work for all classes that adopt the `UIAppearance` protocol (`UILabel`, `UIButton`, etc).

For eaxmple, the following code will change the text alignment of all labels in your app:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

IIRC, `UINavigationBar` does not support `UIAppearance`, meaning that you'll need to use a custom label for the title.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all those elements with a thin custom class of your own creation that you can wire up to change this property based on the locale.

Comment: that again boils down to handling each and every element manually. I was wondering if apple provided any standard method for doing this.